# Как сделать отступ от заголовка?

Tags: html, css

Привет всем. Подскажите, как можно сделать отступ.

```
codepen.io/anon/pen/jPJwVV
```

В примере можно увидеть, что на 1-м слайде все нормально(тестовый вариант, делал быстро), но, если заголовок имеет больше длину, то он налезает на описание. Как сделать, чтобы блок с описанием всегда имел отступ от блока с заголовком, к примеру, 15px. 
Кнопка "Далее" всегда должна быть внизу как и сейчас.

Comment: ну а как же ему не налезть на описание, если описание с фиксированной высотой, да еще привязано к низу блока. у вас там в коде много "воды", не касающейся вопроса. еще и плохо форматировано, лень разбираться. Но я бы избавился от всех `position: absolute` первым делом.

Answer (score 1):

Элементы `<p>` абсолютно позиционированы по отдельности. Поместите их в общий стиль и там укажите position:absolute

[Пример](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvWzRv)

Comment: Если я задам отдельный див для <p>, то слайдер не будет корректно работать.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте через `margin` Скажите, если не получится.

Comment: Из-за абсолютного позиционирования margin не очень подходит. Ведь, если заголовок будет на 1 строку, то отступ будет такой, как и при двойной строке, например.

Comment: А если relative?